# Laravel - How to display Username in Password Reset Notifications Email

Tags: laravel

I am working on a project using Laravel-5.8 as backend and Angular-7 as frontend. I am sending Email Notification for Password Reset to the user. Current, I have:

PasswordResetController.php

```
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
        ]);
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        if (!$user)
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'We can\'t find a user with that e-mail address.'
            ], 404);
        $passwordReset = PasswordReset::updateOrCreate(
            ['email' => $user->email],
            [
                'email' => $user->email,
                'token' => str_random(60)
             ]
        );
        if ($user && $passwordReset)
            $user->notify(
                new PasswordResetRequest($passwordReset->token)
            );
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'We have e-mailed your password reset link!'
        ]);
    }
```

App\Notifications\PasswordReset:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class PasswordResetRequest extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    protected $token;
    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
     {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
            ->action('Reset Password', url('http://localhost:4200/#/reset-password-submit?token='.$this->token))
            ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

The fields in the user table are:

> first_name,last_name, email, password

I am trying to add the user's first name in the password reset notification email. At the moment, Laravel notification emails starts like:

> Hello!

I want to change it to

> Hello Solomon!

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using

```
$user->notify(
    new PasswordResetRequest($passwordReset->token)
);
```

the `$notifiable` variable in `toMail` is an object of the user model, so you can display the username in the mail.

Simply add a the chaned `->greeting()` method for nice formatting with your greeting string as a param

```
return (new MailMessage)
    ->greeting('Hello '.$notifiable->first_name.' '.$notifiable->last_name)
    ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
    ->action('Reset Password', url('http://localhost:4200/#/reset-password-submit?token='.$this->token))
    ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications#formatting-mail-messages), you could place `->greeting('Hello!')` in your `toMail` method. You could pass in user details to this class and show the username in the `greeting` method

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a variable from a controller.

```
if ($user && $passwordReset)
$user->notify(
    new PasswordResetRequest($passwordReset->token, $user)
);
```

And then you need to access like that.(`App\Notifications\PasswordReset:`)

```
protected $token;
protected $user;

public function __construct($token, $user)
{
    $this->token = $token;
    $this->user= $user;
}

public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
    ->greeting('Hello '.$this->user->first_name.' '.$this->user->last_name)
    ->line('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.')
    ->action('Reset Password', url('http://localhost:4200/#/reset-password-submit?token='.$this->token))
    ->line('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.');
}
```